# Bug with [2048] tag

Tags: bug, status-completed

The [2048](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2048) tag on the main site was not allowing edits, saying that the tag was banned.

Comment: I failed to see the point in this when you first posted it - a [meta-tag:bug] which was immediately [meta-tag:status-completed], by yourself?! - but evidently you succeeded in catching a dev's attention, so something must have worked :-)

Comment: @randal'thor - Just wanted to inform the community that I'd changed the tag (to see if there were any objections or better suggestions).

Answer (score 4):

Sorry about this; this was my bad. It was impacting an API. I verified that we didn't have pure numeric tags on *some number* of sites, but I obviously failed and didn't thoroughly check all of them, which is my error. I will find another approach for the problem that I was trying to fix. The code has already been reverted. 2048 should work fine now; let me know if you need me to migrate the tag back to what it was. Again, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It has been renamed to [2048-game](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2048-game).